# quantile on a matrix in long format

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to compute quantiles on a matrix represented as a data.table in long format (rowid, colid, value).  To do this I am converting it into Matrix::sparseMatrix and then computing the quantiles.  I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this? (using R 3.2.1 and data.table 1.9.5 from github)

```
require(data.table)
require(Matrix)

set.seed(100)
nobs <- 1000   #num rows in matrix
nvar <- 10    #num columns in matrix
density <- .1  #fraction of non-zero values in matrix

nrow <- round(density*nobs*nvar)
data.dt <- unique(data.table(obsid=sample(1:nobs,nrow,replace=T), 
        varid=sample(1:nvar,nrow,replace=T)))
data.dt <- data.dt[, value:=runif(.N)]

probs <- c(1,5,10,25,50,75,90,95,100)

#approach 1
system.time({
data.mat <- sparseMatrix(i=data.dt[,obsid], j=data.dt[,varid], x=data.dt[,value], dims=c(nobs,nvar))
quantile1.dt <- data.table(t(sapply(1:nvar, function(n) c(n,quantile(data.mat[,n], probs=probs/100, names=FALSE)))))
quantile1.dt <- setnames(quantile1.dt, c("varid",sprintf("p%02d",probs)))[order(varid)]
})

#approach 2
system.time({
quantile2.dt <- data.dt[, as.list(quantile(c(rep(0,nobs-.N), value), probs=probs/100, names=FALSE)), by=varid]
quantile2.dt <- setnames(quantile2.dt, c("varid",sprintf("p%02d",probs)))[order(varid)]
})

all.equal(quantile1.dt, quantile2.dt)
```

**Update**
I found the answer to this and wanted to share, in case somebody else finds it useful!  My original question was approach 1.  The better way to compute the same is approach 2.  The real advantage of approach 2 is seen when nobs and nvar is large.  For example, when nobs=100,000 and nvar=1,000  approach1 takes 27sec while approach2 takes 4sec!

Comment: what do you mean by deep format? This is not a term used in the Matrix package.

Comment: long format (edited question as well).  For a very sparse matrix, the long format is obviously a much more efficient way of storing the data since the zeroes are not saved.  In the above code, data.dt is in long format whereas data.mat is in wide format. thx.

Answer (score 1):

By your description, it was a little hard (for me) to see what you wanted to do, so I'll make a basic example.

```
set.seed(100)
nrow <- 10
ncol <- 5
prop <- 0.1
nobs <- round(prop*nrow*ncol)
s1 <- c(5,7,8,8,9) # sample(1:nrow, nobs, replace=T)
s2 <- c(1,3,3,4,4) # sample(1:ncol, nobs, replace=T)

# unique pairs
arr <- unique(array(c(s1,s2), dim=c(nobs,2)))

# random num for each unique pair
s3 <- c(0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.2, 0.4) # runif(length(arr[,1]))

# show data
data.frame(v1=arr[,1], v2=arr[,2], v3=s3)

#   v1 v2  v3
# 1  5  1 0.1
# 2  7  3 0.5
# 3  8  3 0.8
# 4  8  4 0.2
# 5  9  4 0.4
```

In this case, the sparse matrix representation is:

```
sm <- sparseMatrix(i=s1, j=s2, x=s3) # since all pairs are unique here

# row 1 corresponds to s1=1, ..., row 9 corresponds to s1=9
# column 1 corresponds to s2=1, ... column 4 corresponds to s2=4
sm

# [1,] .   . .   .  
# [2,] .   . .   .
# [3,] .   . .   .  
# [4,] .   . .   .  
# [5,] 0.1 . .   .  
# [6,] .   . .   .  
# [7,] .   . 0.5 .  
# [8,] .   . 0.8 0.2  
# [9,] .   . .   0.4
```

The values corresponding to `s2=1` are `(0,0,0,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0)'`, and so on. We can find the quantiles of each of these columns with:

```
q <- c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0) # quantiles 
data.table(t(sapply(1:4, function(n) c(n,quantile(sm[,n], q)))))

#    V1 25% 50% 75% 100%
# 1:  1   0   0   0  0.1
# 2:  2   0   0   0  0.0
# 3:  3   0   0   0  0.8
# 4:  4   0   0   0  0.4
```

(Note that here there are 9 zeros but there should be 10. Notice that if I had use `1:ncol` in the `sapply()` function above, it wouldn't have worked since `sm` only has 4 columns. I think that using the `sparseMatrix()` function for quantiles might not always work for this reason)

What is the fastest way to do this? Suppose the variables above `s1, s2, s3, nrow, ncol, arr` are defined as above. Suppose you want the quantile of `s3` for `s2 = 1`. You could do this for instance

```
tmp <- s2==1
quantile( c( s3[tmp], rep(0, nrow-sum(tmp)) ), q)
```

This kind of approach could potentially be better, but I think that for large data sets the `sparseMatrix` approach should work well